# Should someone programming using VB Forms use MVC pattern

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns, coding-style

I am refactoring some code and am working with another programmer. I suggested refactoring the code to follow the MVC pattern to remove all the plumbing from the forms code and put them into seperate classes such as a controller and model class for database. He disagreed with me saying that VB is not meant for MVC and that we should put the code into DLL's. I agree with DLL's but put the MVC into the DLL's is my opinion. Have I got the wrong idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a desktop application? because in that case it would be more useful a pattern of MVVC. In any case, I recommend that you seek information from Domain Driven Development (DDD). Here's an article from a practical example =>http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/768664/Introduction-to-ASP-NET-Boilerplate

Comment: Thanks for that. Just needed some guidance.